# how to use group by in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get 164 records in sql query but i'm getting 90,000 records

My MySql query gives correct output

```
SELECT distinct(sourceadd), 
       starttime,
       destadd,
       calltype,
       bw,
       adjustdur 
FROM cma 
where starttime between '2011/07/01' and  '2014/07/02'   
and calltype = 'ad hoc'  
group by sourceadd 
order by sourceadd asc;
```

My M$Sql query gives more number of records it's wrong

```
Select * from 
  (SELECT distinct(sourceadd), 
          starttime,
          destadd,
          calltype,
          bw,
          adjustdur,
          ROW_NUMBER()over(order by sourceadd) as row 
   FROM cma 
   WHERE starttime between '2011/07/01' and  '2014/07/02' 
   and calltype= 'ad hoc') cma 
where cma.row > 0 
and cma.row <= 100000
```

Comment: You can have have something like SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.col1 > 10 GROUP BY a.col2 HAVING a.col2 < 10 . Can you give as some data to work with and the desire output?

Comment: share your table schema! and be more clear.

Comment: the first query is returning 164 is I think because you have distinct 164 "sourceadd". That is giving correct result because you are grouping by it.

Comment: It looks to me that you are joining `dma` and `cma` without any criteria which links them, resulting in a cartesian product. This seems wrong. You should have something like `and dma.col1 = cma.col1`. Using `DISTINCT` can cover up the problem, but it is better to write the query correctly in the first place.

Comment: I cannot comment on M$SQL, but in MySQL, DISTINCT is not a function, so those parentheses are redundant and misleading. Also, in the absence of any aggregating functions, GROUP BY is similarly inappropriate and misleading. MySQL forgives the aberration. M$SQL does not. In short, if your first query returns a correct result, this is by luck rather than design.

Comment: deleted the answer will post the new working one